# How can I change the default bucket of a google-cloud-based hadoop-enable cluster after I created it?

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-platform, google-hadoop

After I create a google-cloud-based hadoop-enable cluster, I want to change the default bucket to a different one, how can I do that? I can't find the answer in google cloud doscumentation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a cluster by hand, using [bdutil](https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/bdutil), using [Cloud Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc) or through some other means?

**bdutil**

If you used bdutil, see the [choose a default file system](https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/setting-up-a-hadoop-cluster) section in the setup documentation.

**Cloud Dataproc**

If you used Cloud Dataproc, you can access any bucket to which your project has permission by using the `gs://` uri. If you want to connect your cluster to a new bucket for logs, you will have to create a new cluster, unfortunately.

**Other method**

If you used a different method, like the "click to deploy" launcher, I recommend you give Dataproc or bdutil a try.